# Integrated VGA and DisplayPort to power dual monitors?

Tags: windows-7, vga, multiple-monitors, displayport, integrated-graphics

I'm trying to add a second monitor to my work Windows 7 hp PC. It's a low-profile model so won't take a full height graphics card with 2 outputs. It does have a DisplayPort socket though.

Is it possible to have a 'stretched' screen setup using the integrated VGA socket to one monitor and the DisplayPort (probably via a DP to DVI adapter) to another?

**Update**
Plugged in a [DP to DVI adaptor](http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?hl=en&xhr=t&q=displayport%20to%20dvi%20adapter&cp=20&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1044&bih=869&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=18320053521042421158&sa=X&ei=rRgcTqmsD4PIhAfo9rzqBw&sqi=2&ved=0CF0Q8gIwAQ) and it worked. Cheap and simple!

Comment: Is there no way for you to get a low end card with two ports?

Comment: @Michael. The only half height ones I've been able to find have one port. The 'low profile' cards with 2 ports all seem to have a full height back plate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is. You'll just need to make sure that the BIOS is set to have both enabled.

Comment: Ta. I'll give that a go after the weekend.

Comment: Couldn't find an entry for this in the BIOS but got a DP to DVI adaptor (about £7) and worked straight off  :¬)

Answer (score 1):

hey companies like ATI and Nvidia have been making low power and low profile cards for years. They are cheap and fit in any computer with a PCI-E slot. Example: [image]

Comment: Something like that would be ideal but the only ones I can find for sale are the 3 port, full height ones, e.g. http://goo.gl/2bUKB